# Where does ISPConfig store its per-website SSL config files?

Tags: 14.04, webserver

My ubuntu 12.04 webserver is dead. Unfortunately.

But I have a non-working backup in the form of a .tar.gz archive (one for / and one for /var partitions).

I have a new, 14.04 server with a clean ISPConfig install, and I would like to get the certificates from the old server back (generated by startssl, so I can't get new ones easily).

Where should I look in my backup to find these certificates?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am indeed using apache. I did the setup using the howtoforge guide (apache, php, bind, dovecot, postfix). I have per-websites ssl certificates. I would like to get all of them back. Initially I did a copy/paste of the certificates content in ISPConfig. But I don't know where it stored them.

Comment: good! then my answer should point you to the directories and files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be anywhere on your system. During setup of the SSL you provided a directory where to install them. If you followed a how-to the most likely directory would be `/etc/apache2/ssl`.

To make it easier to find the: the files are

```
ca.pem
private.key
sub.class1.server.ca.pem
ssl.crt
```

Beside that: your virtual host in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` will also have alterations to point to port 443 and have something like this:

SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt                           
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private.key                        
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
```

(this is all based on the assumption you used apache and the often used `/etc/apache/ssl/` in how-to's).

---

General searching for files in a tar.gz:

```
tar tvfz {tarfile}.tar.gz /etc/apache2/ssl/ /etc/apache2/sites-*/
```

will find it. `tar xvfz` to extract files.

Comment: Thank you for the extra tip about searching in tar files. I am currently extracting everything in a temp folder to lookup the files. I may need other files. That's why I am extracting everything.

Comment: Solution: looking at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` showed me the `.vhost` files. These contain the location of the ssl files. Thank you so much for your help.